# Copy files from Minion to Another Minion using Saltstack

Tags: salt-stack

I want to copy files from one minion to another using saltstack state.

I did not find a useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no direct way to do this within salt. salt just was not made for this. however the best option would be to use something made for this purpose and use salt to work with it. such as rsync

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.rsync.html